# Firebase Send Message to Topic and get report

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

There is some way to get success/failure when send message with FCM to a specific topic?
Right now the response return an array like:

```
[
"name" => "projects/project-1234/messages/123456789"
]
```

Instead when I use to send message to specific tokens it will return an array with success and failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping from the topic to the subscribed tokens happens asynchronously, so there is no detailed report in the API response.

The most details are in the delivery report, which you can [export to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#what-data-exported). Although I'm not 100% certain, I think the token is in the `instance_id` field in there.